# How can I reduce current drawn by micro SD card module?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am using a servo along with a sensor and micro SD card module and speaker in arduino uno in order to play a wav file at certain conditions . But when i run the whole system the sd card module is consuming high current and the servo stops working as the current in that is in order of some micro amps. So please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: SD cards *do* use a lot of current. You just need to supply more to your circuit.

Comment: I think the problem is somewhere else. Most likely the SD library you are using is blocking all interrupts while it's reading the SD card. When there are no interrupts the servos don't get any signal for a moment, and will stop working.

Answer (score 2):

another good practice might be to add a Transistor to your Systems so that you can physically disconnect parts of your System from the power rail while not in use. this will obviously decrease power consumption...

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to drive all of that from the Arduino regulator. The answer is to get a higher current power supply. You might even need to add filter capacitors on the 5V rails "right in front" of your different systems to protect them from voltage drops when other systems suddenly draw large amounts of current from the 5V rail.